# How to create a hierarchical CMS page in Magento?

Tags: php, content-management-system, magento

How would I go about creating a hierarchical CMS page in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your question that you want to have a tree-like navigation structure for a series of CMS pages?  This features comes natively with Magento Enterprise, however you will need to purchase or write a custom extension for Magento Community

Answer (score 1):

Clever CMS is now a paid extension available here https://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-cms-tree.html

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but you can [make it better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of both [free](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/657/navigation-bar-administrator/) and [commercial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/3854/cmspro/) extensions which might help, and there are probably more than this if you search. I've tried neither so be sure to check the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

CMS page hierarchy is a feature of Magento Commerce (Magento Enterprise Edition). If you use Magento Open Source (Magento Community Edition) — then it is not possible out of the box. You might check this module [CMS Pages Navigation Magento 2](https://www.magesolution.com/cms-pages-navigation-for-magento-2.html)